# How can I hang an application?

Tags: windows, freeze

I want to hang a Windows application (exe) for testing purposes. The goal is to see the (Not responding) status in the Task Manager.

Comment: You might want to consider attaching a debugger.

Comment: @DragonLor Please, post your comment as an answer. I'll select it. I have used x64dbg to pause the application. The status 'Not responding' doesn't appear, but the app is hung. Thx.

Comment: Process Explorer has a pause/resume processes function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Attaching a debugger will pause the application.

- The application is suspended when a debugger is attached. Although this may not trigger the "Not Responding" indicator, it will effectively stop execution of the application until it is allowed to continue in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use a project called "Win32 process suspend/resume tool"
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2964/Win-process-suspend-resume-tool